# remove selected option from jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i am using jquery autocomplete and its working fine, my requirement is that the value which is selected much be removed from the drop down how can i achieve that? js and html are below

**js**

```
var classes=[];
            $.ajax({
                    url: "classes.htm",
                    dataType : "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        var val = data;
                        var arr=val.toString().split(",");
                        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
                            {
                                classes.push(arr[i]);
                            }

                    }
                    ,
                    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });

            $( "#cls" ).autocomplete({
                source: classes
            });
            $("#cls").bind("autocompleteselect", function(event, ui) {

            });
```

**html**

```
<input type="text"  name="cls" id="cls"/>
```

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just overwrite the `source` option of your Autocomplete element when one element of your list is selected:

```
$("#cls").bind("autocompleteselect", function (event, ui) {
   // Remove the element and overwrite the classes var
   classes.splice(classes.indexOf(ui.item.value),1);

   // Re-assign the source
   $(this).autocomplete("option","source",classes);
});
```

Be careful because when the user select an option, it will be removed automatically.

Comment: thank you, that worked like a charm. I was unaware of splice :).